# Script Runs Fine On 1Machine, Gives Error On Other

Tags: shell-script, sed

I'm running the following script on multiple machines, It runs fine on couple of machines, but now on others, and gives the error.

The script  & errors are given below.

> SCRIPT:

```
host="$(/bin/hostname)";
qSize="$(/usr/sbin/exim -bpc)";
qLimit="100";
sTo="someuser@somedomain.com";
sFr="root@"$hostname;


if [ $qSize -ge $qLimit ]; then
echo "There are "$qSize "emails in the mail queue" | sed 's/^/To: '"$sTo"'\nSubject: *ALERT* - Mail queue o
n '"$host"' exceeds limit\nFrom: '"$sFr"'\n\n/' | sendmail -t

else

        echo -e "There are "$qSize "emails in the mail queue"

fi
```

> ERROR!!

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 79: unterminated `s' command
```

Does anyone have any idea, what the error could be?

Comment: Could you clarify whether that broken line (stopping at `Mail queue o` and resuming with `n '"$host"` is in the actual script, or a copy/paste error?

Comment: Could be copy paste, cause its on $host

Comment: Put a `set -x` line at the beginning of the script and run it again. It will show the actual command lines (with variables expanded).  Maybe one of those shell variables has a newline in it.

Comment: Why are you even using `sed` to insert a few lines before the output of an echo statement?  This could (and **should**) be done by either echo-ing a a multiline double-quoted string or redirecting a heredoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
echo "There are "$qSize "emails in the mail queue" | sed 's/^/To: '"$sTo"'\nSubject: *ALERT* - Mail queue o
n '"$host"' exceeds limit\nFrom: '"$sFr"'\n\n/' | sendmail -t
```

is painful to read.   Worse, even if you re-format it to make it readable, the useless use of `sed` is bizarre - just plain wrong.  You're using `sed` to insert the email headers before the output of the echo statement.  That makes no sense at all.

In short, you do not need to use `sed` here, and you should not be using `sed` here.  It adds nothing but extra complication and opportunities for bugs.

Do something like this instead:

```
sendmail -t <<EOF
From: $sFr
To: $sTo
Subject: *ALERT* - Mail queue on '$host' exceeds limit

There are $qSize emails in the mail queue

EOF
```

or like this:

```
subject="*ALERT* - Mail queue on '$host' exceeds limit"
message="There are $qSize emails in the mail queue"

echo "$message" | sendmail -f "$sFR" -s "$subject" "$sTO"
```

or even like this:

```
{
  echo "From: $sFr"
  echo "To: $sTo"
  echo "Subject: *ALERT* - Mail queue on '$host' exceeds limit"
  echo
  echo "There are $qSize emails in the mail queue"
} | sendmail -t
```

Even this is better:

```
echo "From: $sFr
To: $sTo
Subject: *ALERT* - Mail queue on '$host' exceeds limit

There are $qSize emails in the mail queue" | sendmail -t
```

In short, almost any other way of piping multiple lines of text into another program (`sendmail`, in this case) is preferable to the way you're doing it.

Comment: @Sollosa it's worth putting in a little effort to make your scripts readable - if you start doing that, you'll thank yourself for it when you have to fix or improve one of your scripts weeks or months after you wrote it.  Pick a style you like, that makes sense to you, and use it consistently.  Same if you're just trying to figure out what it does and how it works, because you forgot what you wrote it for. BTW, whitespace (both indentation and extra linefeeds) greatly improves readability and doesn't cost a cent :)

Answer (score 1):

You have two lines

```
echo "There are "$qSize "emails in the mail queue" | sed 's/^/To: '"$sTo"'\nSubject: *ALERT* - Mail queue o
n '"$host"' exceeds limit\nFrom: '"$sFr"'\n\n/' | sendmail -t
```

should be a single line

```
echo "There are "$qSize "emails in the mail queue" | sed 's/^/To: '"$sTo"'\nSubject: *ALERT* - Mail queue on '"$host"' exceeds limit\nFrom: '"$sFr"'\n\n/' | sendmail -t
```

i.e. the error was likely introduced by the way in which you copy/pasted it to this machine.

The fact that the problem is at column 79 (80 column display?) kinda confirms it.

Comment: No the last line is linked with else part of command, I just added it because I wanted to see if email function really works.. cause mail queue is significantly too low to generate email. Once it's verified, I'll comment out last line

Comment: @Sollosa Or your sed should be in one single line or will produce an error, since the first sed line can not stand on it's own.